# Roboelectric unit tests are unresponsive

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

I am unit testing my MVP Android app and I cannot run Robobelectric unit tests on my system. Any test that utilizes Roboelectric is unresponsive and hangs forever.

For example the following test runs forever:

```
import static com.google.common.truth.Truth.assert_;

@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 23)
public class FakeTest {

    @Test
    public void testShouldFail() {

        assert_().fail("Fail!");
    }
}
```

Android Studio just shows a spinning icon indefinitely on any Roboelectric test. Running the tests from gradle in the terminal hangs as well but doesn't show any indicators.
[image]

Here is what my `build.gradle` testing dependencies look like:

```
// Unit testing
testCompile(
        'junit:junit:4.12',
        'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19',
        'com.google.truth:truth:0.28'
)
// Roboelectric 3.1-SNAPSHOT is the latest that supports API 23
testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1-SNAPSHOT') {
    exclude group: 'commons-logging'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```

System information:

OSX: `10.11.4`

Android Studio: `2.0.0-rc2`

JDK: `1.8.0_40`

Android SDK: `23`

Gradle Tools: `2.0.0-rc2`

Roboelectric: `3.1-SNAPSHOT`

Gradle: `2.10`

I am completely stumped. There is no debug output from Roboelectric that is saying something is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So any test is hanging. if you run it from command line do you see same behaviour?

Comment: Yes. I mentioned this in the OP.

Comment: `2.0.0` is now out. Also, be careful about the robolectric snapshot.

Comment: Can you try Robolectric-3.0?

Comment: @EugenMartynov I have the same issue with Roboelectric 3.0 as well.

Comment: Do you have hanging test if you try to clone this project https://github.com/emartynov/android-template-project and run tests

Comment: @EugenMartynov I solved my problem. Turns out one of my gradle plugins was conflicting with Roboelectric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this https://github.com/frogermcs/AndroidDevMetrics gradle plugin was conflicting with Roboelectric.

Comment: Would be great to know which plugin is doing harm so other will be warned

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was AndroidDevMetrics. If you disable the activiyMetrics it works fine.

```
AndroidDevMetrics.Builder androidDevMetricsBuilder =
          new AndroidDevMetrics.Builder(this)
               .enableActivityMetrics(!isRoboUnitTest())
              .enableDagger2Metrics(true)
              .showNotification(true);
      AndroidDevMetrics.initWith(androidDevMetricsBuilder);

 public static boolean isRoboUnitTest() {
    return "robolectric".equals(Build.FINGERPRINT);
  }
```

Comment: I ended up disabling AndroidDevMetrics in my tests entirely by writing a wrapper around it and injecting a no-op version in my tests.